# Protractor + Simple-SSH how to get it sync together in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, ssh, jasmine, protractor

I'm writing some e2e tests with protractor .
During one test I have to physically connect to device with ssh so i decided
to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-ssh

When I use simple-ssh inside my protractor test's , Jasmine doesn't wait for simple-ssh and it is not working.

Is there any possibility to sync that together ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that by using done() from Jasmine 2.0 
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/stips/using-jasmine-2.0s-new-done-function-to-test-asynchronous-processes.html