# Trying to SSH using protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh, protractor

I'm running protractor on my windows VM and need to execute some commands on a linux VM. I'm trying to use SSH to do the same. I've tried using 'simple-ssh', 'remote-exec' and 'ssh-exec. The problem with all of them is the same, the protractor test completes without any error but the SSH connection is not established. Strangely it doesn't throw any error as well, I've tried giving wrong IP, but still, no error is thrown. I've tried SSH over python with same machine, it works flawlessly.

here is a piece of code from documentation that I directly tried to use.

```
var ssh = new SSH({
             host: 'xx.xx.xxx.xx',
             user: 'xxxxx',
             pass: 'xxxxx'
         });

         ssh.exec('ls -lh', {
            out: function(stdout) {
                console.log(stdout);
            }
        }).start();
```

Comment: Can you provide the full test?

Comment: I've written it as a dummy test, just for testing this functionality. It has one 'it' block and pretty much two 'console.log' statements on both sides of the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

I used [ssh2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2#start-an-interactive-shell-session) package to establish an interactive SSH session. Then I synchronized it with jasmine using [done()](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/stips/using-jasmine-2.0s-new-done-function-to-test-asynchronous-processes.html) in jasmine 2.

Used Maciej Ciach's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38789096/13397072) for solving sync problem.

Here's an 'It' block that runs flawlessly

```
it("trying ssh connection", function (done) {
        var conn = new Client();
        conn.on('ready', function () {
            console.log('Client :: ready');
            conn.shell(function (err, stream) {
                if (err) throw err;
                stream.on('close', function () {
                    console.log('Stream :: close');
                    conn.end();
                }).on('data', function (data) {
                    console.log('OUTPUT: ' + data);
                });
                stream.end('ls \nexit\n');
                done();
            });
        }).connect({
            host: 'xx.xx.xxx.xx',
            port: 22,
            username: 'x',
            privateKey: require('fs').readFileSync('file_path')

        });
    })
```

Obviously, you need to add your public ssh key to the list of trusted keys on your server first.
You can read about it [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-linux-unix/).

If you are on windows then execute those commands in Powershell.